# AxisLabel Stacked Column Chart using MsWeb Chart

Tags: webchartcontrol

I'm using Ms Web Chart to have stacked column chart. The Axis Label are coming properly if the no of columns are <= 9. if it is more than 9 then the lables are not coming properly.

```
for(int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 10; pointIndex++)
{
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(45, 95),0));
    Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(5, 75),0));
    Chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(5, 95), 0));
    Chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(35, 95), 0));

    Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[pointIndex].AxisLabel = "test" + pointIndex;  
}

Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = "StackedColumn";
Chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartType = "StackedColumn";
Chart1.Series["Series3"].ChartType = "StackedColumn";
Chart1.Series["Series4"].ChartType = "StackedColumn";
```

if the pointindex is less than = 9 then it is coming fine if it is > 9 then the axis labels are coming properly

Answer (score 0):

```
<AxisX LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64"  Title="Instrument Type" IsLabelAutoFit="true" TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 15pt, style=Bold" LabelAutoFitStyle="LabelsAngleStep90" Interval="1" > <LabelStyle Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 7pt, style=Bold" /> </AxisX>
```

Add this `LabelAutoFitStyle="LabelsAngleStep90" Interval="1"`  to your axis info . you can see as many labels as you want